# Integral of $\cos(3x) \cos(4x) \cos(5x)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

The integral $$\int_0^{\pi/8}\cos(3x)\cos(4x)\cos(5x) \,dx$$ is equal to $k/24$. Find the constant $k$.

So far, I assume that the best way to solve this question is to solve the integral and compare the answer to find $k$.

I have thought about rewriting the integral by using the identity 
$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$ or $\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$,
but that results in a very long and confusing function. 
I don't see any possible substitutions.

Please help!

Comment: I suspect $$\cos 5x\cos 3x = \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos 8x + \cos 2x\right)$$ will make it bearable. May be worth a try.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

Hint
$$\cos 5x\cdot\cos 3x\cdot\cos 4x
\\=\cos 5x\cdot\frac{(\cos 7x+\cos x)}{2}
\\=\frac{\cos 5x\cdot\cos 7x+\cos 5x\cdot\cos x}{2}
\\=\frac{\cos 13x+\cos 2x+\cos 6x+\cos 4x}{4}$$

Comment: Sorry, how do you go from cos3xcos4x to (cos7x+cosx)/2 ?

Comment: since $\cos x\cos y=0.5(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y))$

Answer (score 2):

Adding together the following trig identities:
$$\cos(A+ B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B$$
$$\cos(A-B) = \cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B$$
gives
$$2\cos A \cos B = \cos(A+B) + \cos (A-B)$$
and hence
$$\cos A \cos B = \dfrac{\cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B)}{2}$$
You can apply this identity to reduce your integral to a sum of cosines, which can be easily integrated.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use the formula for $\cos(5x+3x)$ and $\cos(5x-3x)$ to show that

$$\cos 5x \cos 3x \equiv \tfrac{1}{2}(\cos 8x + \cos 2x)$$

Substitute this into $\cos 5x \cos 3x \cos 4x$, expand and then apply the same trick to the expansion.

Answer (score -1):

Using 
\begin{align}
\cos(x) \cos(y) &= \frac{1}{2} \, (\cos(x+y) + \cos(x-y) ) \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right) &= \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{4}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{2}\right) &= - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -1
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\cos(3 x) \cos(4 x) \cos(5 x) &= \frac{1}{2} \, (\cos(2 x) \cos(4 x) + \cos(4 x) \cos(8 x) ) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, (\cos(2 x) + \cos(4 x) + \cos(6 x) + \cos(12 x)).
\end{align}

The integral in question becomes:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\pi/8} \cos(3 x) \cos(4 x) \cos(5 x) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \int_{0}^{\pi/8} (\cos(2 x) + \cos(4 x) + \cos(6 x) + \cos(12 x)) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{48} \, [ 6 \, \sin(2 x) + 3 \sin(4 x) + 2 \sin(6 x) + \sin(12 x) ]_{0}^{\pi/8} \\
&= \frac{1}{48} \, \left( 6 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right) + 3 \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) + 2 \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{4} \right) + \sin\left(\frac{3 \pi}{2} \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{24} \, \left( 1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \\
&= \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt{2}}{24}. 
\end{align}